# Remove duplicates in a dictionary, duplicates meet certain conditions

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

In Denmark we have 3 different types of levels, that you can have certain classes on. A, B and C. I have a list of dictionaries, that contains each employee's class, and which level they had that specific class on. Now the problem is that if an employee has had Math on A, it will automatically add Math B and Math C to the employee's classes. If an employee has had Math on B, it will also show Math C. I need a way of removing the 'duplicates'. The order of hierarchy is as follows. (They will always have the actual class they intended, and the ones below it, if there are any)

A First, B Second and C last

Since the dictionaries are in a list, this is how I currently access them:

```
def subject_filter(subjects):
all_subjects = pickle.load(open("pickles/subject.p", "rb"))
for x in all_subjects:
    for subject in x.values():
        # Code here :)
```

We can always assume, that the last char of the subject is the level they had it on. Therefore that wont be a problem, we can access it with `subject[-1]`

Example output:

```
Samfundsfag A
Samfundsfag B
Samfundsfag C
Samfundsfag Folkeskole
Samtidshistorie B
Spansk A
Spansk B
Spansk C
Spansk Folkeskole
Statistik C
Teknologi A
Teknologi B
Teknologihistorie C
```

As you can see there are some abnormalities, where the last char isn't A, B or C we just want to ignore those.

Intended output:

```
Samfundsfag A
Samtidshistorie B
Spansk A
Statistik C
Teknologi A
Teknologihistorie C
```

Comment: This would be a much better question if there were input and desired output data.

Comment: I added it @timgeb Sorry

Comment: That does not look like dictionaries. And where's the input?

Comment: I looped over the values in the dictionaries, to just print out the values. As for the input, we get the data from an API and tailor it to our liking using databases, and pickles.

Comment: Perhaps we could add it all to another dictionary, and if we know there are 3 duplicates (excluding the last char), we know that the class is A, and if it's 2 we know the highest class was B and so on

Comment: But you are not working with formatted text. You are working with dicts. You take a dict input and want a dict output. So why do you want us to work with formatted text instead?

Comment: I don't know, I just thought plain text would be better to work with.

Comment: No, because you are not asking a question about manipulating plain text.

Comment: Can you use `pandas` in your solution?

Comment: @timgeb You're welcome to propose a solution, just using dictionaries.

Comment: @JonSG I'm not really familiar with the library

Comment: @Sonny I can't since you refuse to share the dicts your are working with.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using `pandas` with `.groupby().first()` but since you are not familiar with that I would go with a more manual approach based on adding grades to dictionary of your course in reverse order so that the "last" grade per dictionary "wins"

```py
## ---------------------------
## Hard coding your data, but I'm guessing based on your existing code that you
## might set it like:
## ---------------------------
## data_in = [
##     cell for row
##     in pickle.load(open("pickles/subject.p", "rb"))
##     for cell in row
## ]
## ---------------------------
data_in = [
    "Samfundsfag A",
    "Samfundsfag B",
    "Samfundsfag C",
    "Samfundsfag Folkeskole",
    "Samtidshistorie B",
    "Spansk A",
    "Spansk B",
    "Spansk C",
    "Spansk Folkeskole",
    "Statistik C",
    "Teknologi A",
    "Teknologi B",
    "Teknologihistorie C",
]
## ---------------------------

data_out = {item.split(" ")[0]: item for item in sorted(data_in, reverse=True)}
for item in sorted(data_out.values()):
    print(item)
```

Giving us:

```
Samfundsfag A
Samtidshistorie B
Spansk A
Statistik C
Teknologi A
Teknologihistorie C
```

Comment: I added the code as follows: 

```def subject_filter(subjects):
    all_subjects = pickle.load(open("pickles/subject.p", "rb"))
    print(type(all_subjects))
    for x in all_subjects:
        subject_list = []
        for subject in x.values():
            subject_list.append(subject)
        data_out = {item.split(" ")[0]: item for item in sorted(subject_list, reverse=True)}
        for item in sorted(data_out.values()):
            print(item)```

Nothing changed tho. Giving me the same output as before

Comment: If this does not work you will need to provide more details about your data. I am literally using the input data you provided to construct the output you provided.

Comment: I didn't downvote it. I'll try and provide more data for you, when I'm home